# Having difficulties with normalizing an histogram in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, normalization

- I'm working with an histogram plotted over and on the right of a scatter.
- I've already tried the normal function inside `plt.hist(norm=1, or density=True)`, and with that I obtain an histogram with y-axis size approximately 2, 5. I know that if I grow the bin size I can low that y-axis value, but the work I'm trying to replicate doesn't have a bin bigger than 0.2.

#### Code:

```py
x,y=columns of a predetermined table

left, width = 0.1, 0.7
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.7
spacing = 0.05

rect_scatter = [left, bottom, width, height]

rect_histx = [left, bottom + height + spacing, width, 0.2]

rect_histy = [left + width + spacing, bottom, 0.2, height]

plt.figure(figsize=(9, 8))

ax_scatter = plt.axes(rect_scatter)

ax_scatter.tick_params(direction='in', top=True, right=True)

ax_histx = plt.axes(rect_histx)

ax_histx.tick_params(direction='in', labelbottom=True)

ax_histy = plt.axes(rect_histy)

ax_histy.tick_params(direction='in', labelleft=False)

ax_scatter.scatter(x, y, s=30, marker='*')

binwidth = 0.1

ax_scatter.set_xlim((-1, 0.7))

ax_scatter.set_ylim((-0.9, 0.9))

bins = np.arange(-10, 10 + binwidth, binwidth)

ax_histx.hist(x, bins=bins, normed=1, color='chartreuse')

ax_histy.hist(y, bins=bins, orientation='horizontal', normed=1, color='darkmagenta')

ax_histx.set_xlim(ax_scatter.get_xlim())

x_histy.set_ylim(ax_scatter.get_ylim())
```

- P.S.: I've looked in other posts, and tried for a long time fixing it, but i'm really lost. Also, I'm new in programming and statistics. Therefore, if you can, use easy terms please.
- I'm addressing a screenshot of the graphic I plotted with this function, and another with an example of the one I'm trying to achieve (the values are not supposed to be the same).
- If you need anything else to help solve my problem, please, be free to ask. Thank you

[image: plot of my histogram]

[image: Example of histogram I intend to achieve]

Comment: With `normed=True`, or rather `density=True` since normed is depreciated and density replaced it, the area under the hist graph is 1. i.e. if you sum bin values time your bin size which is 0.1, you'll get 1. Why would you like the maximal occurrence to be normalized to 1?

Comment: Normed histograms don't usually have y-axis size <=1? I think that by achieving this I can understand more easily my graphic due to the common connection with percentage (maximum 100%).